# Android get firebase push ID in RecyclerView OnClickListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using generic **Recyclerview** to populate data from firebase, and I want to know how to get push ID from **firebase** so that I can proceed to the detail screen?

**I tried to use**

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = getRef(position);
```

**In onBindViewHolder but it's not working**

I'm aware that i can get push ID from **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**, but for this case i'm using generic **Recyclerview**.

```
private class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simple_item_recyclerview, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = getRef(position);
        final String post_key = mDatabaseReference.getKey();

        holder.tvShopTitle.setText(myList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvShopAddress.setText(myList.get(position).getAddress());

        holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Key", post_key);
                mIntent.putExtra("Title", myList.get(position).getTitle());
                getActivity().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You already look up `post_key` in your code, so what's the remaining problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i can only get post_key value when i use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but in this case i'm using generic Recyclerview so using getRef will give me an error "Cannot resolve method getRef(int)"

Comment: None of your code seems to attach a Firebase Database listener yet. I recommend you spend some time in the [Firebase documentation on reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data). It doesn't rely on FirebaseUI and explains reading from the database on a level closer to what your code is aiming to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good news :) i finally found a solution, i have included the answer in the post for anyone who might find it helpful

Comment: Good to hear. Can you post it as an answer, instead of in your question? That will make it clearer to others (and the system) that you've found your own answer, without having to read the (by now quite long) question body.

Comment: Yeah sure i'll do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

Here is a method where i use it to insert new value to firebase database:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Post").push();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Title", "dummy title");
    map.put("Address", "dummy address");
    map.put("PostID", myRef.getKey());
    myRef.setValue(map);
```

Now that i have push id stored in firebase database, i can then retrieve that value along with other data and populate recyclerview as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final String post_key = myList.get(position).getShopID();

    holder.tvShopTitle.setText(myList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvShopAddress.setText(myList.get(position).getAddress());

    holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("Key", post_key);
            mIntent.putExtra("Title", myList.get(position).getTitle());
            getActivity().startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is how my Pojo class looks like:

```
public class MyPojo {

    private String Title;
    private String Address;
    private String ShopID;

    public MyPojo() {
    }

    public MyPojo(String title, String address, String shopID) {
        Title = title;
        Address = address;
        ShopID = shopID;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public String getShopID() {
        return ShopID;
    }
}
```